# How do I automatically synchronize Google Docs with Dropbox?

Tags: sync, google-docs, dropbox

I would like to be able to edit one of my Google Docs on another computer, save it online (not download it to that computer and upload it to Dropbox), and then be able to go back to my home computer and have the file already synced to my computer.

How do I automatically synchronize Google Docs with Dropbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer I think is with [Syncplicity](http://www.labnol.org/internet/office/backup-and-sync-google-docs-files/5188/)

Comment: how about a Mac alternative? Syncplicity dropped their Mac beta for some reason.

Comment: You have to pay AGAIN? Oh my gosh... how much money they can squeeze out from a normal person? They are insane. Seriously.

Comment: @Shiki: Not insane. Good businessmen. :)

Comment: Syncplicity is competing product to Dropbox thus answer is not correct. Syncplicity is one of alternatives to Dropbox (with their own cloud storage and client). They will synchronize Google Docs with their own storage, but Syncplicity *will* not synchronize Dropbox with Google Docs.

Answer (score 4):

Dropbox [just announced](http://blog.dropbox.com/?p=593) that this feature is in development.

Comment: Indeed; I was excited to see that post! Hopefully it'll be available soon.

Comment: @nhinkle still excited about it? All links are broken now! I was hoping if you have any news...

Answer (score 2):

**Probably**, but not with Dropbox. Dropbox exists for local syncing, GDocs exists entirely in the cloud. You'd want a dedicated application for that, but I don't know if such a thing exists. If it has a good API, though, it shouldn't be too hard to hack together.

Answer (score 2):

The best actual solution is https://www.insynchq.com/
This is a dropbox equivalent that sync with google docs.
SB

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the most efficient way to sync Google Docs and Dropbox is to use cloudHQ. http://cloudHQ.net

And here is why:

Here are some benefits:

1. cloudHQ will actually upload Google Docs document into Dropbox in MS Office format: so you can edit them using MS Office from your Dropbox
2. cloudHQ can, optionally, upload your Dropbox MS Office document in Google Docs format so you can use Google Docs interface to edit them
3. cloudHQ can establish two-sync but without "replicating deletion": so basically Google Drive can be become backup/archive of your Dropbox (or vice-versa)
4. There is no need to have your PC/home computer running for sync to happen: as soon as you edit file for example via iPhone/Android or your iPad, the changes will be instantly copied directly between Google servers and Dropbox server.
5. You can sync / merge / consolidate multiple Dropbox and Google Drive accounts
6. You can sync just a portion of your Dropbox / Google Drive account

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use Google Gears on both computers and tweak it to save files to your Dropbox folder, but this would be a total hack and there are very few chances it might work.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://getsatisfaction.com/dropbox/topics/sync_dropbox_with_google_docs) Dropbox getsatisfaction feature request and vote for it if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I know of 4 options:

- [CloudHQ](https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox/synchronize/google_drive) is expensive, but does it very well.
- Some desktop apps do the trick (such as [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/), by far the best option I know of).
- Zapier, IFTTT and cloudwork only go so far - they sync new files, don't keep synced after they change.
- Manually downloading files as PDF (or DOCX, XLSX, etc) might still be the simplest free reliable option.

Unfortunately I could find no Google Docs Connected App that do the trick, and dropbox have no app market, just their API, to which nobody found a way to do it properly, other than cloudHQ, as far as I know.

A good option to using freaking MS DOC format is going with http://stackedit.io or something similar such as the awesome [penflip](https://www.penflip.com/). But there's nothing as easy to collaborate with than Google Docs, with other non-tech-savy people.

I don't think there's any *free* way to automatically sync docs and dropbox without a machine.

Answer (score 0):

A service called Cloudseed has emerged to solve this issue, currently in closed beta: http://cloudseed.me/